# $.widget is not a function with blueimp jQuery file uploader intermittent

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload, jquery-file-upload, blueimp

I'm trying to use blueimp's jQuery file upload. I *should* have all of the requirements linked in this page. I don't see any file loading errors. What's happening is that the file upload button intermittently doesn't work and Firebug throws the following errors:

```
TypeError: $.widget is not a function


$.widget('blueimp.fileupload', {

jquery....load.js (line 87)
TypeError: $(...).fileupload is not a function


$('#pdf-upload')
```

I'm not sure what causes this error intermittently.

**Header:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<title>Admin</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<link href="/css/admin.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jscripts/gen_functions.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jscripts/validation.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jscripts/selectbox.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jscripts/admin_products.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/mainhold/6DKkzyUpi/ckeditor.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jscripts/qfax-events-admin.js"></script>
    <!--Google Analytics Code Here -->
    <!--- eg the below link would only show on the index page
    <link rel="canonical" href="" />
    --->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0">
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://css3-mediaqueries-js.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/css3-mediaqueries.js"></script>
<![endif]-->


</head>
```

**Footer:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) {
    var $currentPaymentDiv = $('#check-payment');

    $('#pdf-upload')
    .fileupload( {
        'url' : $('#fileupload').data( "url" ),
        'dataType' : "json",
        'done' : function( e, data ) {
            data = data.result;

            if( data.success ) {
                if( data.rows instanceof Array ) {
                    for( var i=0, length=data.rows.length; i<length; i++ ) {
                        var row = data.rows[ i ];

                        if( row.success ) {
                            $('#no-pdfs').hide();
                            $('#case-pdf-header').after( 
                                    '<tr><td class="tabledata" valign="top">'+
                                        '<a class="delete-pdf" href="'+row.delete_url+'"><i class="fa fa-times"></i> | '+
                                        '<a class="edit-pdf" href="'+row.edit_url+'"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i>'+
                                    '</td>'+
                                    '<td class="tabledata" valign="top"><a href="'+row.view_url+'">'+row.filename+'</a></td>'+
                                    '<td class="tabledata" valign="top">'+row.sent+'</td>'+
                                    '<td class="tabledata" valign="top">'+row.modified+'</td>'+
                                    '<td class="tabledata" valign="top">'+row.created+'</td>'+
                                    '<td class="tabledata" valign="top">'+row.login_staffname+'</td></tr>'
                                    );
                        }
                        else {
                            alert( "Error uploading. "+row.message );
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else {
                alert( "Error uploading. "+data.message );
            }
            //console.log( data );
        }
    } );

} );
</script>
<script src="/jscripts/jQuery-File-Upload-9.11.2/js/jquery.iframe-transport.js"></script>
<script src="/jscripts/jQuery-File-Upload-9.11.2/js/jquery.fileupload.js"></script>
<!--[if (gte IE 8)&(lt IE 10)]>
<script src="/jscripts/jQuery-File-Upload-9.11.2/js/cors/jquery.xdr-transport.js"></script>
<![endif]--></td>
                                </tr>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        </table>

                        <br /><br /><br /><br />
                        <br /><br /><br /><br />


</body>
```

Comment: Are you running jQuery in no conflict mode?

Comment: I don't think so... console.log( jQuery==$ ); in the Firebug console it outputs "true". It's also notable that when I switch jQuery( document ) to $( document ) it won't work when I browse to the link but only when I refresh the link after browsing to it.

Comment: Seems to be that when I comment out CKEDITOR it works. Now to try and find the best of both worlds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What fixed it was putting the CKEDITOR **after** the jQuery includes.

**Resulting header:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<title>Admin</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<link href="/css/admin.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jscripts/gen_functions.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jscripts/validation.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jscripts/selectbox.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jscripts/admin_products.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/mainhold/6DKkzyUpi/ckeditor.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jscripts/qfax-events-admin.js"></script>
    <!--Google Analytics Code Here -->
    <!--- eg the below link would only show on the index page
    <link rel="canonical" href="" />
    --->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0">
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://css3-mediaqueries-js.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/css3-mediaqueries.js"></script>
<![endif]-->


</head>
```